# How to use parent theme functions in child theme functions.php file?

Tags: functions, child-theme

Parent theme required a foo.php file, and inside that file is a baz() function.
I want to use that baz() function in functions.php of the child theme without recall foo.php file again.
Are there any ways to do that?

Comment: Please explain the with code and what you have tried already.

Comment: @Abhik I edited my question. Hope you can understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can wait for the parent theme's `functions.php` to load you can hook to the `after_setup_theme` or `init` actions and do what you need there.

Comment: So i hooked it into after_setup_theme and it worked! Thanks you!